# Flutter error throw from another class is not caught by the calling function

Tags: android, flutter, error-handling

I have a this bloc implementation in flutter so once the bloc is triggered then it will call this apiCall() function as below

```
Future apiCall() async {
    print("calling api now ");
    var future = repository.getList().catchError((err) {
      print("api_bloc:Error is " + err.toString());
      if(err is AuthError){
        print("Auth error");
      }      
    });
  }
```

This will call the repository function repository.getList() which is as below.

```
Future<CountyListRoot> getList() async {

      String url = "countyList";
       try{
      final countyListJson = await NetworkUtils.postNoToken(url).catchError((err) {
          print("county list repository is " + err.toString());
          if(err is AuthError){
            print("catch at repository Auth error");
            throw AuthError('Auth Error: ');
          }
      });
      print("countyListJson" + countyListJson.toString());
      return CountyListRoot.fromJson(countyListJson);
      }
      catch(exception){
        if(exception is AuthError){
          print("catch at repository Auth error");
        }
        print("Exception");
      }


  }
```

In the above it calls the NetworkUtils.postNoToken(url) which does the actual post and catch and throw the errors. So by right it should be caught in the above function but it doesnt. Below is the actual post.

```
static dynamic postNoToken(String url) async {
        var uri = host + '/api/'+ url;

        try {

            final response = await http.post(
                uri,
        headers: {

            );

            final code = response.statusCode;
      print("Network util post reply code:"+code.toString());
      print("Network util post reply response body:"+response.body);
            if(code==401){

                throw AuthError('$code Auth Error: '+parseMessage(response.body));
            }
            else if(code>=500){

                throw UnknownError('$code. Server error: '+parseMessage(response.body));
            }
            else if(code>=400){

                throw Error4xx(' $code Wrong request : '+parseMessage(response.body));
            }


            return response.body;

        } catch (exception) {
            print(exception);

        }
    }
```

So in the scenario above I purposely created a scenario which generate

```
if(code==401){

                throw AuthError('$code Auth Error: '+parseMessage(response.body));
            }
```

But it not caught or shown in the repository function.
Below I created the models too.

```
class UnknownError {
  final String message;

  UnknownError(this.message);

}

class DiffError{
  final String message;

  DiffError(this.message);
}

class AuthError {
  final String message;

  AuthError(this.message);
}

class Error4xx {
  final String message;

  Error4xx(this.message);

}
```

How to fix this error catching and passing so that I can finally show via some snackbar or pop-up accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

When you catch an exception you need to `rethrow` it so that it can be caught by the caller.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-rethrow-to-rethrow-a-caught-exception

So everywhere you currently catch an exception you should `rethrow` if it's not handled by that specific catch.

```
void misbehave() {
  try {
    dynamic foo = true;
    print(foo++); // Runtime error
  } catch (e) {
    print('misbehave() partially handled ${e.runtimeType}.');
    rethrow; // Allow callers to see the exception.
  }
}

void main() {
  try {
    misbehave();
  } catch (e) {
    print('main() finished handling ${e.runtimeType}.');
  }
}
```

Comment: so every place where I put the throw I should replace with rethrow is it ?

Comment: the issue is that the first throw is also not caught so how to rethrow in my case?

Comment: No, it should go in your catch block. Every time you catch an exception but don't handle it you should rethrow so that the caller can catch it. I've added some example code.

Comment: I dont get in my case the first place I throw is like this throw AuthError('$code Auth Error: '+parseMessage(response.body)); so how to convert this to rethrow cause I saw rethrow must be rethrow; just end with semicolon

Comment: also another problem this throw is not caught in the exception cause I based on return response code from my http

Comment: the problem the error is not caught here wait NetworkUtils.postNoToken(url).catchError((err) {